# Can i search calendar and web-table on the basis of active element instead of particular value?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

As i am getting problem in locating specific value in flight schedule page..i want to search on the basis of table rows and column..is it possible and how?

Following is webpage details :-
Calendar :- http://www.vueling.com/es
Web table :-https://tickets.vueling.com/ScheduleSelect.aspx

```
dummy.findElement(By.cssSelector("#datePickerContainer > div.ui-datepicker-group.ui-datepicker-group-first > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(5) > a")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000); 
dummy.findElement(By.cssSelector("#datePickerContainer > div.ui-datepicker-group.ui-datepicker-group-first > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(2)")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Question 1 :-
How can i click an active element in calendar?
Question 2 :-
How can i search an enabled element in flight schedule page using table row n column value.
Please..help me regarding this...Thank you

Comment: Please share the code you tried.

Comment: dummy.findElement(By.cssSelector("#datePickerContainer > div.ui-datepicker-group.ui-datepicker-group-first > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(5) > a")).click();
      Thread.sleep(5000); 
    
dummy.findElement(By.cssSelector("#datePickerContainer > div.ui-datepicker-group.ui-datepicker-group-first > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(2)")).click();
   Thread.sleep(2000);

Answer (score 0):

In your Question1 for https://tickets.vueling.com/ScheduleSelect.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

the class has different names you can try

```
   List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

        for(WebElement ele:list){           WebElement enabled_ele = ele.findElement(By.tagName("td"));
           String className = enabled_ele.getAttribute("class");
           System.out.println("Class name = "+className);

           if(!className.contains("ui-state-disabled")){
               enabled_ele.click();
           }        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..But it is asking me to create getDriver()..After creating that again asking to change findelements to find element and also to import searchcontext..

Comment: hi, sorry man forgot to remove that part, edited the code. Now try for it.